# VBA - Create, edit, and hyperlink shape

Tags: vba, excel, shapes

In my tool I am trying to create a shape, rename it, have it move with the shifting widths of columns, and hyperlink it to a summary sheet.  This is what I have so far, thanks in advance.

```
For s = 7 To Sheets.Count
    With Sheets(s)
        Dim GoToSummary As Shape
        Set GoToSummary = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 400, 153 + 12.75 * 2, 300, 50)

        .Shapes(GoToSummary).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Go Back To Summary"
    End With
Next s
```

I know this is not correct, that is why I am reaching out, because I couldn't find anything similar to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close!

```
Sub test()
Dim GoToSummary As Shape

For s = 7 To Sheets.Count
    Set GoToSummary = Sheets(s).Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 400, 153 + 12.75 * 2, 300, 50)
    GoToSummary.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Go Back To Summary"
    Sheets(s).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=GoToSummary, Address:="", SubAddress:="Summary!A1"
Next s

End Sub
```

- `Dim GoToSummary` outside of the loop
- Once you've defined GoToSummary with Set, you can just refer to it directly, i.e. as `GoToSummary` instead of `.Shapes(GoToSummary)`
- Added the hyperlink as well

Comment: Great, just one question, how do I keep the shape the same size.  Some sheets have wider columns than others, which makes some wider than others.

Comment: Before the hyperlink line, try adding `GoToSummary.Placement = xlMove`
 and `GoToSummary.Width = 300`